# Get the IDs of multiple files

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way I can list the ID's of multiple files inside a folder on my Google Drive. Can this be done via a script?

I am using a script in Sheets that will format them one by one and it is time consuming to open each file and copy the ID from the URL.

Comment: check the documentation for files.list and then add a q parameter to get only the files in the folder you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, got it to output to a spreadsheet with:

```
function listFilesInFolder(id) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderidgoeshere');
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var name;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var id;

  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "ID"]);


  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    id = file.getId()

    data = [name, id]
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }
};
```